# Django QuerySet Regex with MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am trying to use Django QuerySet/Filter with Regular Expression to filter the records in my MongoDB database. For the Python packages, I'm using:

- Django 4.0.3
- djongo 1.3.6
- pymongo 3.12.6

Here's my current attempt (code):

```
import re
from .models import User

regex = re.compile(pattern)
result = User.objects.filter(name__iregex=regex.pattern)
```

However, I get `djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError` every time I use the filter like above.
After looking through StackOverflow, I find out that I can filter by using Django [**raw**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124353/django-mongo-regex-query) but I still want to know if there are any other ways to make the above codes viable.